# Make VirtualMin git Module SMART

Tags: installation, git

I used VirtualMin's git module to setup a private git over http on one of my servers.
I have other servers with git over ssh but this was my first try to setup it over http and with VirtualMin.

Unfortunately, in last few hours I find out that the default VirtualMin's module don't use smart http mode and relay on DAV for pushing commits to the server. Which I don't really like.

Also I tried to move my old repos to this server and I cant use them because there is no /info/ref file. (I also heard that using smart http mode I don't need this file)

In result, I tried to find a document about installing smart git http and found a lot. But I dont think any of them is compatible with VirtualMin or its default git module,

Do any of you people know how I need to customize my git's installation and Apache settings to use smart http protocol with little hurt to VirtualMin and also still be VirtualMin compatible?

I really don't want that my settings and configurations to remove after a VirtualMin update or setting's recreation process that this control panels usually do.

Please share your thoughts on this matter with me. Thanks

OS: CentOs 6.5 x64

Comment: Why are you so tied to Virtualmin? Virtualmin is a *user* tool, not something that a *sysadmin* should be using.

Comment: @EEAA No actually. UserMin is a user tool. VirtualMin/WebMin is an admin tool. Of course you can do lot of these things with bare hands yet it makes it more simple for you. I just don't want any incompatibility because I have users who want to add repos using VirtualMin's interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [Setting up Smart HTTP for Git on Virtualmin](http://blog.echothis.com/2012/07/20/setting-up-smart-http-for-git-on-virtualmin/).

---

From [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) the solution was to switch from ordinary HTTP to Smart HTTP using the git-http-backend executable, which could execute all the hooks and it supposedly much faster too.

1. Copy the git-httpd-backend executable to the /home/domain/cgi-bin/directory and set the permissions to domain:domain. This is to avoid suexec problems.

   ```
   $ cp /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend /home/domain/cgi-bin
   $ chown domain:domain /home/domain/cgi-bin/git-http-backend
   ```
2. On `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, add this to the VirtualHost for the domain:

   ```
   [...]
   ServerName domain.com

   [...]

   # Set the root directory where git repositories reside
   SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/domain/public_html/git

   # By default, the git-http-backend allows push for authenticated
   # users and this directive tells the backend when a user is authenticated.
   SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER

   # Export all repositories
   SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

   ScriptAlias /dev/ /home/domain/cgi-bin/git-http-backend/

   [...]

   # Add this if it’s not already there

   DAV on
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName domain.com
   AuthUserFile /home/domain/etc/git.basic.passwd
   Require valid-user
   Satisfy All

   RedirectMatch ^/git(/+)$ /git/gitweb.cgi
   RewriteEngine off
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

   [...]
   ```
3. And then restart apache. Now all the repos are now available at `http://gituser@domain.com/dev/git/*`, e.g., `http://gituser@domain.com/dev/git/reponame.git`, and all the hooks will execute as expected.

Going forward, when you create a new repo via Virtualmin, you need to do these manual steps:

1. Create an empty file `/home/domain/public_html/git/reponame.git/git-daemon-export-ok`.
2. Create this as `/home/domain/public_html/git/reponame.git/hooks/post-receive` and make it executable by all, and owned by apache:domain:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   #
   # An example hook script for the "post-receive" event.
   #
   # The "post-receive" script is run after receive-pack has accepted a pack
   # and the repository has been updated. It is passed arguments in through
   # stdin in the form
   #
   # For example:
   # aa453216d1b3e49e7f6f98441fa56946ddcd6a20 68f7abf4e6f922807889f52bc043ecd31b79f814 refs/heads/master
   #
   # see contrib/hooks/ for a sample, or uncomment the next line and
   # rename the file to "post-receive".

   # Echo to the client that you’re sending the mail now
   echo "Sending notification email..."
   . /usr/share/git-core/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email

   # Make sure to update the git repo info on the server for pulls by other clients
   git update-server-info
   echo "Updated server info."
   ```
3. As per [this link](http://mapopa.blogspot.com/2009/10/git-insufficient-permission-for-adding.html), set the permissions of the git directory as follows so as to avoid a write-permissions problem when pushing new files in commits (while making sure the gitweb.cgi script is only writable by the owner to avoid suexec errors that would appear in /etc/httpd/logs/suexec.log):

   ```
   $ cd /home/domain/public_html/git/
   $ chmod -R g+ws *
   $ chgrp -R domain *
   $ chmod -R g-w gitweb.cgi
   $ chmod -R g-s gitweb.cgi
   ```
4. Update `/home/domain/public_html/git/reponame.git/config` to match the following:

   ```
   [core]
       repositoryformatversion = 0
       filemode = true
       bare = true
   [hooks]
      mailinglist = email1@domain.com, email2@domain.com
      envelopesender = git-commits@domain.com
      emailprefix = "[REPONAME] "
   ```

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer as you like, but remember to give credit to the blog post writer as he is the one thtt really helped the OP.